# Checking the URI PHP

Tags: php, preg-match, uri

I have a problem with checking the URI. I would like to create a pattern that will accept such a URI:

```
?name=key&name=key
#anchor

foo?name=key&name=key
foo#anchor

foo/bar/*
foo/bar?name=key&name=key
foo/bar#anchor
```

At the moment I have something like this:

```
$path = 'foo';
$uri = 'foo/bar/bb';
preg_match('/^('.$path.'[^\w])[\/\w\S]+$/i', $uri);
// OR
preg_match('/^('.$path.'|'.$path.'(\?|#)[\w\S\=\.&%-]+)$/i', $uri);
```

I would like to simplify it somehow. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you getting full url then it'll work.
You can use `filter_var` with `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL`

Snippet

```
$url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53304342/checking-the-uri-php";
if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    echo "$url is a valid URL";
} else {
    echo"$url is not a valid URL";
}
```

Live [demo](https://3v4l.org/1htOM) 
[filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)

Comment: I did not want it to be @Smartpal, I do not want to confirm it, I want to check it with a specific pattern. I thought I well defined the essence of the problem.